# Raspberry Pi B don't start

Tags: power-supply, usb-power

I try to boot from Rasbperry PI 1B version 2011.12, but it only shows the Red light but nothing happen. I try difference OS with no luck.

The problem is the power?

Comment: Check the power supply is still giving 5V (by measuring between pin#2 and the outer case of the USB. I had a power supply go bad that would light the red led but wouldn't boot the old RPi.

Answer (score 3):

If you tried different OSs, the problem is most likely the power. Check if your power supply is 1.8A. Here's a link to the power supply requirements of the different models of the Pi: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/power/README.md.